# Query: Deduplicate results (from _Click data view query)

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, data-views

I'm trying to add click on a certain alias to a data extension for segmentation purposes, but I find my query erroring with the 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key.' error.
Probably because the same subscriber can have multiple clicks.

How can I extend this query so it only returns the *latest click* by *each subscriber*

```
SELECT c.SubscriberKey, 
m.EmailAddress, 
m.Country, 
m.Language, 
m.Gender, 
m.FirstName, 
m.LastName, 
m.Store, 
m.StoreId, 
c.LinkName
FROM _Click c
JOIN MasterSubscribers m on c.SubscriberKey = m.SubscriberKey
WHERE c.LinkName = 'WeLove_BornholmTable'
AND m.Consent_status = 'Confirmed' 
AND c.EventDate > dateadd(hh,-24,getdate())
AND c.SubscriberKey NOT IN
(SELECT j.SubscriberKey FROM JourneyDE_WeLove_BornholmTable j)
```

I've tried using DISTINCT and tried adding GROUP BY, but have only caused syntax errors so far.
Please guide me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your target Data Extension's primary key is just Subscriber Key, I'd expect a primary key violation since you're joining with a one-to-many relationship (`MasterSubscribers -> _Click`).

I think you can achieve what you want without a JOIN:

```sql
select 
  m.SubscriberKey
, m.EmailAddress
, m.Country
, m.Language
, m.Gender
, m.FirstName
, m.LastName
, m.Store
, m.StoreId
, 'WeLove_BornholmTable' LinkName
from MasterSubscribers m 
where 
m.Consent_status = 'Confirmed' 
and exists (

  select top 1 c.*
  from _Click c
  where c.EventDate > dateadd(hh, -24, getdate())
  and c.subscriberkey = m.subscriberkey
  and c.LinkName = 'WeLove_BornholmTable'
  and c.isunique = 1

)
and not exists (
    select top 1 j.*
    from JourneyDE_WeLove_BornholmTable j
    where j.subscriberkey = m.subscriberkey
)
```

Also, your `c0.EventDate > dateadd(hh, -24, getdate())` will only give you clicks after the current date *and* time 24 hours ago.

If you want clicks on that link in the last 24 hours, I'd suggest using something like this instead:

`and c0.EventDate > convert(date, getDate()-1))`

This will give any clicks after midnight yesterday.

Comment: Thank you, what a powerful way to achieve this. I'm grateful, really! :)